# Using Python CSV and glob to find matching strings and print row

Tags: python-2.7, csv, glob

I have hundreds of CSV files and I'm trying to write a Python script that will parse through all of them and print out rows that have matching string(s). I'll be happy if we can get this to work using one string (and not a list of strings). Using Python 2.7.5. I've figured out so far:

The csv module in Python will print the row with the matching string in a particular column (the eighth column from the left):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('2015-08-25.csv'))
for row in reader:
    col8 = str(row[8])
    if col8 == '36862210':
        print row
```

So the above works for one .csv file. Now I need to parse hundreds of .csv files with glob. The glob module will print out all the file names with this code:

```
import glob
for name in glob.glob('20??-??-??.csv'):
    print name
```

I tried putting the two together into one script but the error message reads:

> File "test7.py", line 6, in 
>   reader = csv.reader(open(csvfiles))
>   TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

```
import csv
import glob

csvfiles = glob.glob('20??-??-??.csv')
for filename in csvfiles:
    reader = csv.reader(open(csvfiles))
    for row in reader:
        col8 = str(row[8])
        if col8 == '36862210':
            print row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open a List - csvfiles is the list you are iterating on.

Use this instead, because open() expects a filename:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! However it doesn't like the two empty rows at the top of each of my .csv files. I've started another post at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216221/python-csv-skip-first-two-empty-rows