# Python csv skip first two empty rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Before anyone marks this as duplicate, I have tried everything from isspace, startswith, itertools filterfunction, readlines()[2:]. I have a Python script that searches hundreds of CSV files and prints the row with the matching string (in this case a unique ID) in the eighth column from the left.

```
import csv
import glob

csvfiles = glob.glob('20??-??-??.csv')
for filename in csvfiles:
    reader = csv.reader(open(csvfiles))
    for row in reader:
        col8 = str(row[8])
        if col8 == '36862210':
            print row
```

The code works with test .csv files. However, the real .csv files I'm working with all have blank first two rows. And I am getting this error message.

> IndexError: list index out of range

Here's my latest code:

```
import csv
import glob

csvfiles = glob.glob('20??-??-??.csv')
for filename in csvfiles:
    reader = csv.reader(open(csvfiles))
    for row in reader:
        if not row:
            continue
        col8 = str(row[8])
        if col8 == '36862210':
            print row
```

Comment: You might want to use `row.strip() == ''` to test an empty line rather than `not row`.

Comment: can you paste the full stacktrace?

Comment: Do you want to skip the first two rows, regardless of their content? Or do you want to skip all empty rows, wherever they appear?

Comment: Just the first two rows...the batch of .csv just happens to have no data in the first two rows. Thanks.

Comment: When I use if row.strip() == ' ' the error message reads AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: The full stacktrace is line 10 in <module>
col8 = str(row[8])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Is it possible for you to use pandas? If yes, you have skip both rows and columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to skip the first two row using `next` instead:

```
import csv
import glob

csvfiles = glob.glob('20??-??-??.csv')
for filename in csvfiles:
    reader = csv.reader(open(filename))
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        col8 = str(row[8])
        if col8 == '36862210':
            print row
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message. reader = csv.reader(open(csvfiles)). TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Answer (score 0):

A csv reader takes an *iterable*, which can be a file object but need not be.

You can create a generator that removes all blank lines from a file like so:

```
csvfile = open(filename)
filtered_csv = (line for line in csvfile if not line.isspace())
```

This `filtered_csv` generator will lazily pull one line at a time from your file object, and skip to the next one if the line is entirely whitespace.

You should be able to write your code like:

```
for filename in csvfiles:
    csvfile = open(filename)
    filtered_csv = (line for line in csvfile if not line.isspace())
    reader = csv.reader(filtered_csv)
    for row in reader:
        col8 = str(row[8])
        if col8 == '36862210':
            print row
```

Assuming the non-blank rows are well formed, ie, all have an 8th index, you should not get an `IndexError`.

**EDIT**: If you're still encountering an `IndexError` it probably is not because of a line consisting of only whitespace. Catch the exception and look at the row:

```
try:
    col8 = str(row[8])
    if col8 == '36862210':
        print row
except IndexError:
    pass
```

to examine the output from the CSV reader that's actually causing the error.  If the row is an object that doesn't print its contents, do instead `print list(row)`.

Comment: My original script worked even if there were blank rows in the body of the .csv file. However, having the two blank rows at the top seems to be the problem. When I tried your script, I get this error. col8 = str(row[8]) IndexError: list index out of range